# is electromagnetic phenomena and particle behavior dependent on dark matter?

Tags: dark-matter, particle-physics, thought-experiment

Dark matter permeates space and coalesce s in its own gravitational attraction. It neither absorbs or emits light or interacts well with baryonic matter. It deflects light on a path and is the sub structure the most known form of matter is attracted to into what resembles a network of webs. I know this much at least. There are things I don't know. DM is more abundant then baryonic matter, which itself experiences EM phenomena. Perhaps by following another set of "rules": does DM function as an  invariant for EM phenomena? 
and subsequently act as a limiting factor for the permissible behavior of baryonic matter and light?

Comment: i don't think there is any evidence or theoretical grounds for believing that EM phenomena require DM (but if there is I'd like to call it the EM-from-DM model!)

Comment: I think that is cool and it makes sense to me. I haven't found anything either to support this but it is predictable an outcome.

Comment: It is not at all clear that dark matter "permeates". High mass models end up with pretty low particle densities.

Answer (score 2):

Dark matter is called "dark" precisely because it doesn't seem to interact with light, i.e. electromagnetism, at all, in the sense of being charged. Only it's gravitational influence can be seen (from which its existence is inferred).

Comment: Okay and since it has no electromagnetic interaction, that pertains to charge and attraction/repulsion. Could DM define a parameter that, although EM does not interact with DM necessarily, may influence the EM spectrum we observe by confining it to a range of function? Given the observed/theoretical properties of DM.

Comment: @nicklee: What do you mean "define a parameter"? There is no "parameter" to adjust in EM left, we *know* the elementary charge pretty well.